# Preserving data on back navigation router with Nativescript & Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm using Nativescript 6 with Angular 8 and I have an issue with the data binded values.

I have two pages. From the first page, I load the values with *queryParams*:

```
private getParamData: any;

public ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) =>  {
        this.getParamData = <any> JSON.parse(params["DataList"]);
    }); 
}
```

When I move to the second page to return to the first one, the data are first correctly binded and then they are *undefined*, few seconds later.

How could I preserve the getParamData?

**EDIT**

Below a link to the Playground for a better understanding: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=a8XYdf&v=19

When you tap on the Home Label then on the Second Label and finally go back, the Second Label becomes the Third

Comment: It's true that queryParams may not be retained on back navigation. You will have to take a snapshot of query params in a local variable and bind the local variable.

Comment: That's what I did with getParamData which is a local component variable.

Comment: I suspect it to act as a pointer or something like that. So when queryParams disappears getParamData is undefined

Comment: I don't think so, can you share a Playground Sample where the issue can be reproduce.

Comment: I edited the post include the link to the Playground. Thank you for your replies !

Comment: You are not taking the params from snapshot, instead you are using subscribe which will be executed whenever there are changes in params. Do you want to see updated query params all the time Or just the ones loaded with the page?

Comment: Just once. When the page is loaded for the first time :)

Comment: Use `this.value = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.yourQueryParamName;` and bind value in template.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works for me!

Comment: If you create a answer, I'll vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preserve the value of query param in a local variable.

```
this.value = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.yourQueryParamName
```

Comment: Thx again for your help